# Why is Fermi energy equal to chemical potential at absolute zero temperature

Tags: semiconductor-physics, definition, chemical-potential, fermi-energy

The probability that an orbital at energy $\epsilon$ will be occupied in an ideal electron gas at thermal equilibrium is given by
$$f(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{exp[(\epsilon-\mu)/k_bT]+1}$$
in kittel's book on solid state physics
it says at absolute zero $\mu$=$\epsilon_F$ because in the limit *T* $\rightarrow$ 0 the function f($\epsilon$) changes discontinuously from the value 1 (filled) to the value zero (empty) at $\epsilon=\epsilon_F=\mu$

$\epsilon_F $ is the [fermi energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_energy).

Can someone explain the math behind this?

Comment: Well, take the limit of the exponential function as T goes to zero.

Comment: @JonCuster Isnt it discontinuous at T going to zero so limit wont exist

Comment: Do you mean the math of why the function you gave becomes a step function for $T\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Discontinuity doesn't matter. You have to take the limit for the two cases: $\epsilon > \mu$ and  $\epsilon < \mu$

Comment: @noah i want to know math behind why epsilon is equal to mu  when $T\rightarrow $ 0

Comment: $\mu = \epsilon_f$. $\epsilon_f$ is the Fermi energy, the energy of the highest occupied state. Taking the limit for the temperature that goes to zero, you have that the occupation is one for energy below $\mu$ and zero above. So $\mu = \epsilon_f$ because it's the energy of the  highest occupied level.

Comment: @Mark_Bell can you work out the limits for me

Comment: I think you can work out those limits yourself just fine. Presume $\epsilon$ is not equal to $\mu$, what happens as $T$ goes to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is asking for the math behind the limit. So
$$f(E)=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(E-\mu)}+1}$$
$$\lim_{\beta \rightarrow \infty}f(E)=\lim_{\beta\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{e^{\beta(E-\mu)}+1}$$

$$\lim_{\beta\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{e^{-\beta|E-\mu|}+1} =1\ \ \text{for} \ \ E<\mu$$

$$\lim_{\beta\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{e^{\beta|E-\mu|}+1} =0\ \ \text{for} \ \ E>\mu$$
$$f(\beta=\infty)=\theta(E-E_F)$$